# set center textview in horizontal linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I am facing issue in android. `TextView` is not showing in center when i set `layout_gravity="center"` in textView. The `TextView` is in horizontal LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

        <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:typeface="normal"
                                android:textColor="@color/themecolor"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: We will need some more details. Is the text more than one line? Is the width match parent or wrap content? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your LinearLayout may have
 `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"`
 change it to
 `android:layout_width = "match_parent` 
and then use the `layout_gravity = "center"` for your TextView

Answer (score 1):

Just give in your layout

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set

```
android:gravity="center"
```

for `LinearLayout` and `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal
```

And your layout width should be match.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:typeface="normal"
         android:textColor="@color/themecolor"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```